# Feeds error in CakePHP returns "Invalid xml declaration"

Tags: php, xml, cakephp

I get an error, whenever I try to open the feed on my web app built on CakePHP:

```
Invalid xml declaration.
Line: 2 Character: 3
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

I don't really know what else I can do to resolve this problem. I did not change anything in the default template of CakePHP. The weird part is that it is working fine on my local box and other two servers but giving error only on one server.

Comment: Try to view the source of the xml file.. It seems like you have did a very common error .. Can u post the source of the xml?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The XML declaration should be on line 1, not line 2. You are probably accidentally adding an extra newline somewhere. Check out your PHP files. There should be **no** blank lines after the closing `?>` tags at the end of your files!

Comment: In fact, you can safely leave off the closing `?>` tags completely; PHP is fine with that, and it reduces the chances of this problem happening. e.g. `<?php echo "Hi!";` is a valid PHP script. (["The closing tag of a PHP block at the end of a file is optional, and in some cases omitting it is helpful when using include() or require(), so unwanted whitespace will not occur at the end of files"](http://uk2.php.net/basic-syntax.instruction-separation))